# Two different way to say a phrase

Tags: phrase-usage

> My computer was delivered with the screen broken.
>
> My computer was delivered in a broken-screened state.

What I want to say is first sentence . Today an english teacher told me that second sentence is grammatical and has same meaning as the firs one but it is not natural and is very odd. I wonder if he is right . He told me that it is used like “ blue-eyed” , blue-eyed is adjective then broken-screened is an adjective.

Comment: it's just that. its exactly what your teacher said, it's just an odd way of saying something when its more natural, and faster to say it the first way.

Comment: Is the first one grammatical?

Comment: Why do you think you should question what your teacher (quite correctly) told you?

Comment: yes, @Foreignstudent the first one is grammatical.

Comment: @ FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Because my teacher is not native speaker . As I couldn’t be sure it is correct I needed to ask .

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, we do get questions here from users who've been told things that are false (or only *marginally* true) by non-native Anglophone teachers. I must just say your proposed alternative phrasing is a "good attempt" though - even though it's definitely *not* "idiomatic", it's typical of the kind of constructions native Anglophone *children* might come out with. Which is actually a good sign, since it shows you're learning (but ***[over-]extending***) underlying grammatical principles just the way native speakers do - way better than rote learning of  "actually acceptable" utterances.

Answer (score 1):

You would not use the second construction in normal English.
The first sentence needs a definite or indefinite article

With a broken screen. (more common)
With the screen broken. This would read correctly but it would be more natural to say the screen was broken when the computer was delivered.

Comment: Right, this is the **obvious** answer.